# Where can I go to get tips / advice on graphic design

Tags: graphics

I am the only guy on a big project - so I have to do everything include the graphical parts such as icons and images.

I'm doing my best but I need some help and my company won't be keen to hiring a real graphic artist to do the work.

I am having trouble scaling down my logo to something that will work in an Icon at 32pix, where would I go to get some tips?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the "sister sites" to Stack Overflow is [doctype](http://doctype.com) for Web Design Q&A. This is probably a good place for such questions.

Answer (score 0):

Go to [alistapart](http://www.alistapart.com/) - lots of interesting stuff there.

K